# Error running MS Access delete query with left join

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using Microsoft Access, I believe from the Office 16 suite.

I am trying to delete records in a `Contacts` table that are:

1. listed as `"Out of Business"` and
2. no longer have any logged donations in a `Donations` table.

(We only keep Donations records for five years to maintain a manageable database size. So once an out-of-business company's Donations have worked their way out of that five-year mark, we can go ahead and delete them.)

I've successfully built a query that returns the results I'm looking for - I can see the results in Datasheet view both when doing a `SELECT` and when switching to `DELETE`.

[image: SQL_View]

However, when I go to run the Delete Query, I get an error message:

> Specify the table containing the records you want to delete.

[image: SpecifyTable_Error_Message]

Here is the SQL code:

```
DELETE Contacts.* 
FROM Contacts
LEFT JOIN Donations ON Contacts.[ContactID] = Donations.[DonorID]
WHERE Contacts.ProcurePreference="Out of Business" AND Donations.DonorID Is Null
```

I am new to SQL code, so am guessing there's something in my syntax that's wonky (although, again, Datasheet view shows exactly what I would expect). Or maybe there's something in the way I've set up my tables and records and relationships that is preventing the final step.

I've searched and read other similar problems on this forum but could not successfully incorporate any of those answers to address my own problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want with NOT EXISTS:

```
DELETE Contacts.* 
FROM Contacts 
WHERE Contacts.ProcurePreference = 'Out of Business' 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Donations WHERE Contacts.[ContactID] = Donations.[DonorID])
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you... I see what you've done there and that helps my understanding. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try using this SQL:

```
DELETE FROM Contacts
WHERE ProcurePreference = "Out Of Business"
AND ContactId NOT IN (SELECT DonorID FROM Donations)
```